# Ruby parameter count rules

Tags: ruby, function, syntax, lambda

What are the rules in Ruby regarding the number of parameters for the various function-like constructs and how they are called?

e.g. I noticed that when blocks with multiple parameters, get passed a single array parameter, it gets expanded, and this does not seem to apply to methods. I often see this with Enumerable module methods on a Hash object.

```
{a: 5}.map{|x| x} # [[:a, 5]]
{a: 5}.map{|k, v| [k, v]} # [[:a, 5]]
[[:a, 5]].map{|x| x} # [[:a, 5]]
[[:a, 5]].map{|k, v| [k, v]} # [[:a, 5]] 

proc1 = Proc.new{|x| x}
proc1.call 5 # 5
proc1.call 5, 6 # 5
proc1.call [5, 6] # [5, 6]

proc2 = Proc.new{|k, v| [k, v]}
proc2.call 5 # [5, nil]
proc2.call 5, 6 # [5, 6]
proc2.call [5, 6] # [5, 6], not [[5, 6], nil]

def f(k, v); [k, v] end
f 5 # ArgumentError
f 5, 6 # [5, 6]
f [5, 6] # ArgumentError

def g(*vargs); vargs end
g 5 # [5]
g 5, 6 # [5, 6]
g [5, 6] # [[5, 6]]
```

However the documentation for [Proc.call](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html#method-i-call) does not seem to mention this.

Then there is also lambda's that are slightly different, methods as Proc's using `&:name`, and maybe some others. And I am not entirely sure `Proc.new{|x| x}.call` is exactly the same as the `yield` in a `method_that_takes_a_block{|x| x}`.

Comment: Suppose you have `arr.each_with_index.with_object([]) { |(o,i),a| .... }`. If `[['cat', 3],[1,2]]` is passed to the block, the values of the block variables are assigned in an unambiguous way, employing *parallel (or multiple) assignment*: `(o,i),a = [['cat', 3],[1, 2]; o# => "cat"; i #=> 3; a #=> [1, 2]`. (Try it!) Now suppose a method is defined `def m(a, b, *c);...;end` and is invoked `m([1,[2, 3]], 4, 5)`. We obtain `a #=> [1, [2, 3]]; b #=> 4; c = [5]`, (no parallel assignment) because that's the only unambiguous way the block variables can be assigned.

Answer (score 7):

The reason behind this is multiple variable assignment and auto-splat

Let's take your proc2 exemple (with an additional intersting use case) :

```
proc2 = Proc.new{|k, v| [k, v]}
proc2.call 5 # [5, nil]
proc2.call 5, 6 # [5, 6]
proc2.call [5, 6] # [5, 6], not [[5, 6], nil]
proc2.call [5, 6, 7] # [5, 6]
```

with ruby you can do a multiple variable assignement:

```
k, v= 5 # => k=5, v=nil
k, v= 5, 6 # => k=5, v=6
k, v= 5, 6, 7 # => k=5, v=6, 7 is not assigned
```

You can also expand an array with the splat operator:

```
k, v= *[5, 6] # => k=5, v=6
```

You can also pack multiple variable in an array with the splat operator:

```
k, *v= *[5, 6, 7] # => k=5, v=[6, 7]
```

ruby can auto splat when suitable:

```
k, v= [5, 6] # => k=5, v=6
k, v= [5, 6, 7] # => k=5, v=6, 7 is not assigned
```

as far as I know auto-splat only applies on variables and `Proc` parameters assignment

Comment: This does not answer the question. You've mostly just repeated what OP already said.

Comment: I've added a line but they are multiple questions and it is difficult to come with a single answer

Comment: So is it that if I have a method def, its like "a, b, c = a, b, c", but for blocks (with yield, or turned into a Proc or Lambda) its like "a, b, c = [a, b, c]"?

Comment: my mistake, it's only for variable assignements and `Proc`. Lambdas won't auto splat. IE: `lambda = ->(k, v){ [k, v]}; lambda.call([5, 6])` will raise an `ArgumentError`

Answer (score 0):

This is leftover from how block arguments used to work before 1.9.

Before Ruby 1.9, blocks used basically assignment semantics for parameter binding. So, if you had a block like

```
{|a, b, c|}
```

and something like

```
yield foo, bar, baz
```

it would *literally* be treated like

```
a, b, c, = foo, bar, baz
```

And when I say "literally", I mean it. For example, the following would be a legal and fully working implementation of an `initialize` method:

```
define_method(:initialize) do |@foo, @bar| end
```

Now, you might say, wait a minute, the method doesn't *do* anything! It is empty! Yes, you are right, the method doesn't do anything, but because blocks use assignment semantics, when I now do

```
Foo.new(23, 42)
```

this will *literally* be interpreted as

```
@foo, @bar = 23, 42
```

You could actually do something *even crazier* than that: you could actually use *setter methods* as block parameters!

```
{|foo.bar, baz.quux|}
```

Now, when I `yield` something to that block, then it will actually invoke `foo.bar=` and `baz.quux=`.

This "feature" was removed in Ruby 1.9+, however. You can no longer use instance variables, global variables, class variables, or setter methods as block parameters. But, there is one useful application of this feature that the designers of Ruby wanted to preserve: automatic destructuring of key-value pairs in `Hash#each`.

So, even though nowadays, blocks don't use *actual* assignment for argument binding, the semantics are still pretty close. This means, for example, that you can ignore arguments at the end, by having fewer parameters. (This means, in turn, when designing an API, you should order block arguments by importance!) Or that you can destructure a single array.

In this regard, `Proc`s behave live blocks, and lambdas behave like methods. (The same is true for the handling of `return`, BTW: in blocks and `Proc`s, `return` returns from the enclosing method, in methods and lambdas from the method and lambda itself.) Useful mnemonic: block rhymes with `Proc`, and method and lambda are both Greek.

Comment: So for Ruby 1.9+ the rule for calling something is "if(type == :block && calls_args.size == 1 && call_args[0].kind_of?(Array) && block_args.size == 1) then call_args = call_args[0] end", for both yield and Proc.call? And using a method as a proc (e.g. "&:my_method"), is identical to "{|x| x.my_method()}" and then follows all block rules?

Comment: @FireLancer: The rule for block argument binding is the same as for assignment (and the rule for `Proc` argument binding as well). `Symbol#to_proc` returns a lambda, not a `Proc`, so the argument binding semantics are the same as for methods, not blocks.